# login using serial port in Linux

Tags: linux, serial-console

I have a slackware machine and I'd like to have a serial console on it. I have a RJ45 console on my hardware. I can now only get output on the console and cannot give any input back to the device. Login prompt appears but I can't type anything into the console. in `/etc/inittab`:

```
s1:12345:respawn:/sbin/agetty -L ttyS0 38400 vt100
```

I have the same problem on ubuntu server 14.04.

Comment: What are you using to get the console? Another computer? A USB-Serial adapter? (If so, what software? `screen`?) A vintage VT100?

Comment: I'm using Hyperterminal and putty from another computer directly connected via serial port. I don't use USB-serial , my computer have serial port.

Comment: I'm not sure about how to solve this in linux, but it is common for FreeBSD systems to be set up to *output only* to the console. I'll do some more research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced cable and problem solved!